# Ubuntu won't find any wifi near me to connect to

Tags: wireless

Ubuntu won't find any wifi near me to connect and I don't know how. I was fine connecting to wifi with windows 7 but now I can't connect to any or find wifi.

[Can't find any wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iMdC.jpg)

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5752 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1600] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell NetXtreme BCM5752 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [1028:01cc]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: This is what showed up: 'grep: A3: No such file or directory 0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no'

Comment: Please copy and paste the command, or be more careful while typing. And post the result TO YOUR QUESTION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

Connect to the internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

After that reboot or run

```
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

Your Wi-Fi should work.

Comment: What would i do now after installation?

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43`